# joining outputs corresponding to their original list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hi I have a nested for loop which processes each element in the list and gives it right alignment and whitespace at the same time.

I have successfully managed to output the individual elements, but I am currently having trouble joining the outputs into their original lists.

Below is my code.

```
input = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 6]]
space = len(str(input[-1][-1]))

for row in input:
    for e in row:
        new_element = '{:>{}d}'.format(e, space + 1)
        print(new_element)

>>> [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 6]]
 # current output
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 3
 1
 3
 6 

 # desired output
 1 1 1
 1 2 3
 1 3 6
```

I have little clue how to reassemble the outputs into their original groupings. What methods can I use?

Comment: If you accept as an answer please no upvote! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are pretty close! You shouldn't use "input" as the name of your list because it is a python function. I changed it to input2. Try this:

```
input2 = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 6]]

for row in input2:
    print(" ".join([str(x) for x in row]))
```

The "join" method joins items in a list by the characters provided in the quotes. You can call join on the list comprehension for list of lists to display each list in the list of lists how you'd like to view it:

out:

```
>>> for row in input2:
        print(" ".join([str(x) for x in row]))
1 1 1
1 2 3
1 3 6
```

if I changed the join to a comma:

```
>>> for row in input2:
...     print(",".join([str(x) for x in row]))
1,1,1
1,2,3
1,3,6
```

If you'd like to retain the whitespace in front of each element and store them into a list of their own (I think I understand):

```
z = []
for row in input2:
    z.append(" ".join([str(x) for x in row]))
print(z)

###['1 1 1', '1 2 3', '1 3 6']

for y in z:
    print(y)

1 1 1
1 2 3
1 3 6
```

Now you understand "join" a little better!

Comment: Is there a way to group them after I have inserted space before each element? In my code I tried to do 1.) give whitespace in front of each element 2.) then group them together according to their original list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would you like to group all of them now like `1 1 1` `1 2 3` `1 3 6`? Like as little strings in a new list with a space in between numbers? perhaps you should edit the question as this answered your original one.

Comment: I currently have the elements printing in separate lines as you can see in my code. My goal is to group those elements in their original list as you can see in my desired output.

Comment: Several of the methods above should do what you ask, I hope this helps!